# Removing colour scale on spplot in R?

Tags: r, colors, plot, scale

I would like to remove the colour scale on the right hand side of an spplot in R. Is there an argument I could add to my plot call that would allow me to do so leaving only the map without a colour legend?

Comment: You might try `colorkey=FALSE`

Comment: Awesome thanks Josh! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try `colorkey=FALSE`, as an additional input to the `spplot` command.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `colorkey=FALSE` works for gridded data, but not for point data. If you need for point data, use `auto.key=FALSE` (from this [thread](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/spplot-without-legend-td3692420.html)):

```r
## prepare data
library(sp)
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid)=~x+y
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)=~x+y

## Gridded data
spplot(meuse.grid, "dist", colorkey=FALSE)
```

[image]

```r
# point data
spplot(meuse, "elev", colorkey=FALSE)   # does not work
```

[image]

```r
spplot(meuse, "elev", auto.key=FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>